# How to highlight focussed window using bug.n

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, themes, bug.n

I'm using [bug.n](https://github.com/fuhsjr00/bug.n) which is based on autohotkey for my window manager on Windows 10 and want the window with current focus to be obvious by having a coloured border like the top left window in the image below.

[image]

I have tried the following customisations in my `Config.ini` but they seem to have no effect. I'm guessing that colours are specified in hex RGB so `0000ff` should be blue.

```
; Customise theme
Config_showBorder=1
Config_borderWidth=3
Config_selBorderColor=0000ff
```

Please could you advise the correct config?

Comment: Have you viewed the configuration examples from the link you have given us? __Config_foreColor_#1=404040;101010;Black;101010;Black;101010;Black;404040;202020__ from _joten_01.ini_ found on this page : https://github.com/fuhsjr00/bug.n/wiki/Configuration-examples   __Please also see__ https://pastebin.com/j5wkZVgm  __Where it defines =black__   etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but I read autohotkey sometimes uses de Delphi syntax for colors.
Delphi: 0x00BBGGRR.

Thus, ***blue*** hex `0000FF` would be `0x00FF0000`

A sure fireway is just use the [aerolite theme](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7935-install-aerolite-theme-windows-10-a.html)